# How to tell search engines about new image URL's?

Tags: pagerank, images, azure

I have just moved my website from a hosted provider to Windows Azure. The page URL's are all the same, but the location of the files is now different.

How can I tell search engines about the new locations of the images? My site is very visual, so ranking of images is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [image sitemap](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636) to tell them where your images are found